# what is Exactly One to many in typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to know exactly what a one-to-many relationship in Type orm

```
@oneTomany
```

Is this command itself a column and the value of this column is saved in another table؟؟

What exactly are its parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One to many relation is used to link one row from your table to multiple rows from another table.

For example it's useful if you have a user table and article table and you want to link articles to a user.

Using TypeOrm, you need to define the `@OneToMany()` decorator in your user entity

```js
@OneToMany(() => ArticlesEntity, articleEntity => articleEntity.user)
@JoinColumn()
articles: ArticlesEntity;
```

You also need to define the `@ManyToOne()` decorator on the other side, here in the **article entity**

```js
@ManyToOne(() => UsersEntity)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
user: UsersEntity;
```

As you can see, the relations needs a `referencedColumnName`. This will be your `userId` referenced in your articles table.

Thanks to this relation, you will have the possibility to get the linked user when finding your article

```js
async findArticleById(id): Promise<ArticlesEntity> {
   return this.findOne({
       where: { id },
       relations: ['user'],
   });
}
```

If you need more informations about it, check the [typeorm documentation about many-to-one-one-to-many relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md)